# How to define an edge is NOT reachable in networkx？

Tags: python, networkx

When calculating the shortest path sometimes we need to consider whether the edge is reachable or not.

I have tried:
Changing the weight to float('inf');
Changing the weight to 0 or -1;
Try to delete the edge by some conditions.

None of these worked.

Comment: What prevents you from just not inserting the edge in the first place?

Comment: Could you also include code snippets showing what you're trying to accomplish, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: what about removing that edge before the shortest path?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not clear what you are trying to do, and this is why you have not received an answer.  A specific example would help.  I do not know what you mean by "reachable", so I cannot help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.